# A question on trigonometric identity

Tags: trigonometry

In solving $$(\sin A-\sin B)^2 + (\cos A + \cos B)^2 = \frac{4}{1+\tan^2 \left (\frac {A+B}{2}\right)}$$

Firstly, I am trying to square $(\sin A-\sin B)^2$  and $ (\cos A + \cos B)^2$ so I get $1+1-2\sin A \sin B+ 2\cos A \cos B$ then what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**
You can use
$$
\cos A \cos B - \sin A \sin B = \cos(A+B)
$$

Also note that $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$, so $\tan^2 x + 1 = \sec^2 x$, so your RHS becomes
$$
\frac{4}{1 + \tan^2 x} = \frac{4}{\sec^2 x} = 4 \cos^2 x
$$
where $x = (A+B)/2$, can you expand this using the double angle formulae?